# Getting junk character if file encoding is utf-16le

Tags: shell, ubuntu, awk, sed

For csv file which encoding is utf-16le. When I try to read  data of csv it gives me junk character

To get file encoding I use below command

```
 file -bi test.csv
```

it gives me text/plain; charset=utf-16le

To read file data I use below command

```
head -n1 test.csv | tr '^' ','
```

it gives me  ��colon1,colon2,colon3

Why it is giving me junk charchater

Comment: Byte order mark, not junk character.

Answer (score 2):

As the csv file is encoded with UTF-16LE, the file starts with the BOM
(Byte Order Mark), 0xff and 0xfe. You can identify it with:

```
head -n1 test.csv | xxd
```

UTF-8 is most commonly used now and UTF-16 is getting less used (including Windows).
Your locale will be also defaulted to UTF-8. So please try:

```
iconv -f UTF-16LE -t UTF-8 test.csv | head -n1 | tr '^' ','
```

which converts the csv file to UTF-8 coding.

Comment: Not able to identify it from head -n1 test.csv | xxd.

Comment: 00000000: fffe 4d00 6f00 6200 6900 6c00 6500 6e00  ..M.o.b.i.l.e.n. .But from this how to identify it.

Comment: The `xxd` command dumps binary data. You can see the "00000000: fffe "
portion at the beginning. "00000000:" is address and "fffe" is data.
It tells the file starts with "0xfffe", the `BOM` for the UTF-16LE encoding.